# Loading Three.js models (.js files) into a hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, 3d, three.js

My thanks in advance for the assistance ,

The problem I have is as follows :
I am trying to create a movable model in three.js , and would like to create a model hierarchy using the JSON variable "model" ,

```
function stackerMove(){
            var models = [
                            {"File Name":"bogie.js","variable":"bogie","Type":"part","Parent":"modelParent","Description":"none"},
                            {"File Name":"swivel.js","variable":"swivel","Type":"part","Parent":"Pivot1","Description":"none"},
                            {"File Name":"boom.js","variable":"boom","Type":"part","Parent":"modelParent","Description":"none"},
                            {"File Name":"bucket.js","variable":"bucket","Type":"part","Parent":"modelParent","Description":"none"},
                            {"File Name":"","variable":"Pivot1","Type":"pivot","Parent":"modelParent","Description":"none"}
                        ];
            // This is overall model storage array for the model. 
            modelParent = new THREE.Object3D();
            modelLoader(models)
            scene.add(modelParent)
            }

            function modelLoader(models){
            for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
                      // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
            if (models[i]["Type"]=="part") {

                      var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                      loader.load( "models/"+ models[i]["File Name"], function(geometry){
                        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x336699});
                        temp = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            //*********(here is the issue )*********
            //console.log(models[i]["File Name"]) does not work here 
            //window[models[i]["File Name"]].add(temp) does not work
                        modelParent.add(temp)

                      });
            } else{
                //all of the pivots would load here.....
            };        
            };
```

at the point marked above *****here is the issue **** , I would like to load each model into the "parent" element of the JSON (models) , however the model json variables do not parse into the loader .load() function ,

to begin with , is this a suitable way to approach this .... or is there a way to parse model(the variable above) element into the array ?

Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried creating var model = models[i] directly inside your for loop and replacing any instance of models[i] with model?

Comment: Thanks , did not get a chance to try that , changed the method to : add individually, but I think your method should work .